# How I can pass to a function the union type without including the tag

Tags: elm

Playing with the Elm [checkboxes example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/checkboxes). I am trying to move the following repetative code in `view`

```
, label []
    [ br [] []
    , input [ type' "checkbox", checked model.underline, onCheck Underline ] []
    , text "underline"
    ]
```

into a separate function and use it three times. So far I have ...

```
makeLabel : String -> Bool -> Msg -> Html Msg
makeLabel caption bool msg =
  label []
    [ br [] []
    , input [ type' "checkbox", checked bool, onCheck msg ] []
    , text caption
    ]
```

and I would use it like

```
makeLabel "underline" model.underline Underline
```

but then I receive the following error

```
Function `makeLabel` is expecting the 3rd argument to be:

Msg

But it is:

Bool -> Msg
```

How do I pass my makeLabel function the correct action to take when a user changes the checkbox?

```
 type Msg
 = Red Bool
 | Underline Bool
 | Bold Bool
```

I don't understand how I can pass to a function the union type (Underline) without including the tag (Underline Bool)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your type signature, rather than the code. Try this:

```
 makeLabel : String -> Bool -> (Bool -> Msg) -> Html Msg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I get it. When the union tag has arguments, it becomes a kind of constructor, a function. That's why the type signature for the union type without arguments is `Underline : Bool -> Msg`.

Comment: Yes, the way type constructors also become functions is considered on the of the few elm 'magic' items. Could you mark the question answered if you feel it is